Probar conexion a la base de datos con PHP en Visual studio code
Hice la conexión de visual studio conde con unas exenciones y la conexión es exitosa(puedo hacer consulta en el propio visual y me carga los datos), me las carga en visual estudio code, ahora mi pregunta ya que no soy un experto y estoy aprendiendo, me gustaría saber como probar esa conexión en php, quiero hacer una programación en php pero no logro hacer las pruebas estoy un poco ignorante en el tema de como realizar la prueba.


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! visual studio no tiene nada que ver con visual studio code. Igual, no entiendo tu pregunta. La conexion no se prueba en un lenguaje.. se hace y listo... o tal vez queres hacer un programa que pruebe conexiones...
